# How to use enum as starting args with aliases

Tags: c++, enums, args

I am trying to use enum as starting args.
It should works as aliases pairs so "i" and "info" should have same value, etc...

I know it is possible to use if/else with flags, but i would like to done this using for eg. switch with int value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace startFlags {
    enum class flag {
        i, info = 0,
        e, encrypt = 1,
        d, decrypt = 2,
        c, check = 3,
        h, help = 4
    };

    void printFlag(startFlags::flag input) {
        std::cout << "Output: " << input << std::endl; //error
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to deal with starting args with aliases.

Comment: Do you have a text book that shows you doing that? Because that's really really weird.

Comment: Just my idea,
I have homework base on some function, but app will be started from console with args.

Problem is how to deal with aliases, my idea is based on enums because there will be only 5 flags.

Comment: So this is about parsing argc and argv?

Comment: It'll work.  You could also do `i, info = i,` (or maybe `i, info = flag:i,` ... not something I've tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `enum class`es if you'd like to print them as `int` (or something else) even though the underlying type is `int`:

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace startFlags {
    enum class flag {
        i, info = i,    // both will be 0
        e, encrypt = e, // both will be 1
        d, decrypt = d, // ...
        c, check = c,
        h, help = h
    };

    void printFlag(startFlags::flag input) {

        // Note cast below:

        std::cout << "Output: " << static_cast<int>(input) << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    printFlag(startFlags::flag::i);
    printFlag(startFlags::flag::info);
}
```